# Trouble searching for two terms using lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have written a following code in my project:

```
final IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(INDEXING_DIRECTORY, true);  
final Query query = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_33, "keywords", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_33)).parse("cats movies");
final TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10, true);
indexSearcher.search(query, collector);
final ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs(0, 10).scoreDocs;
```

The task is very trivial.

I, for example, have a stored record with an indexed "keywords" field. The keywords for example might be similar to "Tons of movies with a funny cats".

The problem is that my code above will return records if search query will be "funny cats" (word order like in the indexed field), but will fail on "cats movies". How should I write my query, so it would match any words order, and if is possible searching for a similar words also?

Comment: Please state your question in the title.

Comment: why all the downvotes? seems a valid question?

Comment: Replaced the word "phrase" with "two terms" in the question. Phrases is not the thing the op wants to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely *"cats movies"* will be parsed as `PhraseQuery`. PhraseQueries respect ordering. What you want is to have a `BooleanQuery` with two `TermQueries` combined with `AND`.

```
final Query query = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_33, "keywords", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_33)).parse("+cats AND +movies");
```

Some more examples are listed [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/11/07/QueryParserRules.html). Some may be already outdated.

Similar words is a rather hard task because you need to have at least some sort of wordlist or database which aligns synonyms.